# Showing and hiding select boxes using javascript/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little bit of test code that intends to have a select box display when a certain option is selected and then hide when that option is changed.

#### HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id="sel1" name="sel1" class="chzn-select">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="sel2" name="sel2" selected="selected" style="display:none">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

#### JS:

```
var selCategory = $('#sel1');
$(selCategory).change(function () {
  $('option:selected').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() ==='2') {
      $('#sel2').show();
    }
    else if($(this).text() ==='1') {
      $('#sel2').hide();
    }
    else if($(this).text() ==='3') {
      $('#sel2').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

This bit of code works great if only this:

```
if ($(this).text() ==='2') {
  $('#sel2').show();
}
```

Is the JavaScript but falls down when adding the else if statements. Also would it be better to display the select box itself or a containing div Tag? The only reason the second select box isn't a chosen-select is that chosen doesn't seem to like elements that are already hidden (problems with width).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$('option:selected')` selector is looking at the options from *all* `select` elements, not just `#sel1`. So `#sel2` is shown (due to "2" selected in the `#sel1`), then immediately hidden (due to "1" selected in `#sel2` itself).  Make sure you're looking only at the value you want:

```
var selCategory = $('#sel1');

selCategory.change(function () {
  selCategory.find('option:selected').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() =='2') {
      $('#sel2').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#sel2').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm ok would the focus on specific select boxes be used by unique selected values for each one? so selected="selected1" selected="selected2"

Comment: No. Rather (as in my code), we're just looking for selected options within `selCategory`

Comment: Gah I'm a fool I didn't see the fact that it was selCategory.find. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it easier, grab the `value` and concatenate the `sel` ID from that:

```
$("#sel1").change(function() {
    $("select:not(#sel1)").hide(); //hide other selects, excluding #sel1
    $("#sel" + this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: yeah that would be easier but the options in the first select box will later be pulled from a database, their id's then being used for the values. If there were a guarantee that these values will never change I would be happy but so far a couple of database changes meant that using the text value caused less headaches if it needed changing.

Comment: Hmm..that indeed does make a difference :) -- do the database values being loaded in align up with the selects, such as choosing option 2 will always show the 2nd select (and so on?) -- Basically, using a giant `if-else` could be a real pain when there could potentially be a way to just go off the selected index or a custom `data-*` value.

Comment: A great answer @tymeJV and one that would work very well if my situation were different. I've marked Paul Roub's answer as correct and I've voted yours up. I really appreciate the help.